# grunt copy - Couldn't load the png image

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am new to grunt.
  I am copying the src folder to build by running the command `grunt copy`.
  But I can't open all png images in the build folder(destination folder).
  I got a fatal error while trying to open the image.
  Errors:
   "Could not load image"
   "Fatal Error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file"

Grunt versions I am using:
grunt-cli v1.2.0, 
grunt v0.4.5, 
grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0.

I have tried with all available links in stack overflow and other sites.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer;

I've done few modifications in the `gruntfile.js`:

- Added `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');` to the end of `gruntfile.js`.
- Modified the `options` like the following:

  ```
  options: { punctuation: '' }
  ```